# How to translate GET keys in Django forms?

Tags: django, internationalization, django-forms

Consider a website using i18n Django functionality.

My question is: how can I translate the GET parameters created by Django forms? For instance,

```
www.example.com/persons?search=topic
```

to

```
www.example.com/pessoas?procurar=topic
```

(pessoas <> persons, procurar <> search)

The url I can do using `ugettext_lazy`, but the parameter I'm not being able since the form is always using the field name (e.g. `search` below):

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):

    search = forms.CharField(required=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to dynamically name the fields in the URI, you're going to have to dynamically name the fields in the form, like so:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext

def MyForm(forms.Form):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields[ugettext("search")] = forms.CharField()
  def search_field():
    return self.fields[ugettext("search")]
```

I've included a helper function so that in your code you can refer to the search field by an unchanging name.